# JSON - jResults/VB error

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to take the value of a result JSON using VB(JSON.NET).

JSON

```
 "paging": - {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 200,
    "total": 6,
  },

  "results": - [
    - {
      "user_id": 010101,
      "name": "Name X",
      "nickname": "XXXX",
      "points": 0
       },
   - {
      "user_id": 0222101,
      "name": "Name X2",
      "nickname": "YYYY",
      "points": 0
       }
```

My code:

```
request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(campos.url), HttpWebRequest)
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())


        Dim rawresp, teste As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
        'Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()


        teste = jResults("results")("nickname").ToString()
```

I need to take the nickname, however do not achieve. In the truth, achieve only take values of the ítem PAGING and any of RESULTS.

But is giving error, he does not achieve to find the values.

Help me?
tks!

Comment: I don't think that this is valid JSON. I don't think there can be minus signs between the key and the value or between the key and the Array indicator "[". I suspect this has been scraped from a HTML page and the - signs are to collapse and expand a tree structure.